# Calling method from a class in different file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say there is a file named

test.py which contain:

```
class calc:

    def add (a,b):
        add = a + b
        print add 

    def sub (a,b):
        sub = a-b
        print sub
```

if I want to call add or sub in another file say ex1.py

I tried

```
from test import calc

t = calc()

t.add(5,4)
```

but it doesn't work.

How do I call add or sub in another file?

if test doesn't have class but function I know we can call by test.add(4,5)

Comment: Pretty sure that's not your real code, since you called the class `calc` but then tried to call something called `calculator`.  Please post actual code.

Comment: BrenBarn, That's my code. I tried to make it short here and kept calculator instead of calc. but you are right it should be calc instead of calculator

Comment: @El'endiaStarman that didn't work. I get an error :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: add() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add `self` to list of arguments, since it gets passed automatically to class methods:

```
class calc:

    def add (self, a,b):
        add = a + b
        print add 

    def sub (self, a,b):
        sub = a-b
        print sub
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. I wanted to learn the module and classes.  I will accept this in 7 minutes :)